# Defining Scopes between multiple JQuery plugins on Same page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am building a website for my sister's marriage. Due to lack of time, i am using and assembling some free plugins. I am also learning Jquery and AJAX on the go.

In the template, when a tab is clicked, contents are loaded inside a central div named **contentholder** using AJAX via JQuery. There are four tabs, one of them is a link to a Photo Gallery.

I am using a downloaded photo gallery demo, which i modified extensively to suit my needs, and to fit inside the dimensions of the content holder div on my main template.
This photo gallery is also in JQuery. It is working perfectly as a separate website.

Now the problem is that when i link my tab (on the template) to load the photo gallery in the **contentholder**. The photo gallery. which is loaded, is not even close to be called anything. **2.** further more, the website goes in to a inception(the movie) state. the template loading inside another, and inside another. On every Tab clicked two inner templates are created.

Both the template and the image gallery uses **CSS-3, JQuery**(both uses different outdated version but replaced it with latest 1.7.1). Both also uses **.ready() and .load() and basic ajax implementations** as common functions.

I think this might be due to common .ready() functions, which both uses to load content.
**Is there a way to define separate scopes between the template and the photogallery, plugins.**

If you can  think of any other cause, please tell it with a solution.

I am not interested to use iframes FLASH or system plugins, just modern web standards.

**EDIT:-** This is the the Base Template i am using
[`http://tutorialzine.com/2010/01/sweet-tabs-jquery-ajax-css/`](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/01/sweet-tabs-jquery-ajax-css/)
And this is the plugin i am using as a photo album
[`http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/12/14/moleskine-notebook/`](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/12/14/moleskine-notebook/)

Tab Three is the one with link to photo gallery which is loaded in the div `content holder`

Comment: I will get a web hosting service and then upload the faulty website if any require to find the solution.

Comment: Still have issues? Yes, please make the whole site available if you want me to check - it's got to do with the combo of the scripts/html....

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is all text and no code, you can only get an educated guess.. :-) And a VERY quick and dirty suggestion...

Your problems probably lies in duplicate ids and classes, not the load/ready. Not all scripteditors name their stuff very unique things, so you may find variables or inserted elements which has the same id.

The very unprofessional way to solve this would be using iframes - defining the scopes as different pages... you'll learn nothing, but will get to the wedding on time

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention. I don't want to use IFrames also. The template updates the central div using ajax. There is no duplicate id or classes, i have ensured it.

Comment: I Edited the question to give the link to the plugins/samples i am using, i didnt give any code as i am uncertain about the exact point of faulty execution. `$(document).ready()` is the only thing i can come up as fault.